# In Excel I want to output the time difference between two dates in days, hours and minutes with only working days being counted

Tags: excel, calculated-columns

I currently have a table keeping records on tasks done and when they were completed in the custom format of "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm". I also wanted another column that works out how long it took for each task to reach the end from the start. As an example, it looks like this:

| Start Date | End Date | Time Taken |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/03/2023 12:00 | 03/03/2023 13:45 | 1 days 1 hrs 45 mins |
| 02/03/2023 12:00 | 07/03/2023 15:35 | 5 days 3 hrs 35 mins |

For the Time Taken column I had used this formula I had found online after doing some research.

```
=INT([@[End Date]]-[@[Start Date]])&" days "&TEXT([@[End Date]]-[@[Start Date]],"h"" hrs ""m"" mins """)
```

I want my results in the Time Taken column to output the difference in that format (so the days, hrs and mins) but also take in working days into consideration. So whilst the first result in the example table is correct, the second one isn't as it is also counting the Saturday and Sunday within that time period.

I am aware that in Excel you could utilise the NETWORK formula to find out the working day between two days but I am unsure if it can be used alongside the formula currently existing. Can someone please let me know the best way to go about this?

Comment: This should work for you --> `=INT(NETWORKDAYS([@[Start Date]],[@[End Date]])-1)&" days "&TEXT([@[End Date]]-[@[Start Date]],"h"" hrs ""m"" mins """)`

Comment: So i have used `-1` at the end because it excludes the `Start Date`